# display angular tags while rending of page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm using AngularJS for localization of my MVC5 web project. I'm able to achieve the objective. But when HTML page renders it first shows angular tags for a fraction of second and then the actual strings values.

**when page is rendering**]

[image]

**rendering completed**

[image]

Kindly suggest if any work around to this.

Comment: You want `ng-cloak`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use any syntax like this for angular-translate :

```
{{'MY_LABEL' | translate}}
```

You should change them by

```
<span data-translate="MY_LABEL"></span>
```

For angular translate, if it's something else using a filter use ng-bind :

```
<span ng-bind="MY_LABEL | translationFilter"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks walfart.. its works for angular tags, but the problems remains same. now images load first and text comes later.

Comment: You mean that don't have unclean text, just it appears later ? This is expected if you load your translations asynchrnously. If you really don't want that you have to delay the bootstrap of your application (module.bootstrap method) until you have loaded all of your translations. But this shouldn't be a problem, i'm using asynchronous loading and the user doesn't really has the time to see the blanks.